# Maven check latest version, only release not snapshot

Tags: maven, mvn-repo

How could I check latest release version of application?

I can check version with: `mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version`.

But this returns snapshot version, is there way to check release versions only?

I'm using Nexus repository for the artifact repository, and Nexus offers API for checking artifacts (this needs credentials). But I would like to know what would be the Maven way for this.

This is for Jenkins pipeline.

Comment: Based on your post you are checking only your own application which does not make sense. The question is: What you are trying to check? A dependency?

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using the enforcer goal:

```
mvn clean install enforcer:enforce -Drules=requireReleaseDeps
```

ref: https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/enforce-mojo.html